# Making Silverlight application work at different browser zoom levels

Tags: css, silverlight, cross-browser, zooming, fluid-layout

I have a Silverlight website which I've configured to work on different resolutions using some JavaScript code and Canvas control ScaleTransform property. That works fine, however, the site is best viewed only when browser zoom is set to 100% or below. When I increase the zoom level, the browser does not provide any scrollbars, and my content gets clipped. I have tried several options, like setting `min-height` in body using CSS, but that does not help. (Note that I need to test the website only on IE)

Here is my scaling code:

```xml
<navigation:Page x:Class="Mynamespace.Homepage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
             xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
             Title="Home"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

<Canvas x:Name="RootCanvas">
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform x:Name="PageScale"
                        ScaleX="1"
                        ScaleY="1" />
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>

    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid"
          Canvas.Left="50"
          Canvas.Top="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="62" />
            <RowDefinition Height="428*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- First Grid Row contains Navigation menu -->
        <!-- Second one contains a scrollviewer that holds a navigation frame -->
        <Grid x:Name="ScrollGrid"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Width="700" />
              <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer1"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Margin="0,0,0,0"
                      Padding="0, 0, 0, 0"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
              <sdk:Frame Name="MainFrame"
                       Width="Auto"
                       Height="Auto"
                       Margin="0,0,0,0"
                       Padding="0,0,0,0">
                <sdk:Frame.UriMapper>
                    <sdk:UriMapper>
                        <!-- some uri mapping here -->
                    </sdk:UriMapper>
                </sdk:Frame.UriMapper>
            </sdk:Frame>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

Here is the code behind for the page:

```c#
    public Homepage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        App.Current.Host.Content.Resized += new EventHandler(Content_Resized);
        App.Current.Host.Content.FullScreenChanged += new EventHandler(Content_FullScreenChanged);
        HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("Homepage", this);
        if (App.Current.Host.IsLoaded)
        {
            HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("ResizeSLContainer");
        }
    }

    [ScriptableMember]
    public void ScaleContainer(double containerHeight, double containerWidth)
    {
        if (containerHeight != 0 && containerWidth != 0)
        {
            ScaleTransform scale = this.FindName("PageScale") as ScaleTransform;
            scale.ScaleX = containerHeight / 744;
            scale.ScaleY = containerHeight / 744; 
        }
    }

    void Content_FullScreenChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (App.Current.Host.IsLoaded)
        {
            HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("ResizeSLContainer");
        }

    }

    void Content_Resized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (App.Current.Host.IsLoaded)
        {
            HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("ResizeSLContainer");
        }
    }
```

And finally the js:

```js
    function ResizeSLContainer() {

        var slPlugin = document.getElementById("SilverlightControl");

        //Scale Canvas
        slPlugin.Content.Homepage.ScaleContainer(slPlugin.content.actualHeight, slPlugin.content.actualWidth);

        //Resize main Container
        if (slPlugin.content.actualHeight > 0) {

            slPlugin.width = (slPlugin.content.actualHeight / 744) * 1005;
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can respond to zoom events in managed code by attaching a handler to the Content.Zoomed event like this:

```
Application.Current.Host.Content.Zoomed += new EventHandler(this.ContentZoomed);
```

Use [zoom design](http://silverscratch.blogspot.com/2011/02/designing-for-browser-zoom-part-2.html) or [adaptive UI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/synergist/archive/2008/09/16/added-high-dpi-support-to-my-silverlight-photobucket-demonstration-application.aspx) to fix the layout.